# Is it possible to merge two YouTube channels?

Tags: youtube, google-plus, account-management

I heard that it is now possible to merge two YouTube channels, using Google+ or something like that. If that's true then:

- How would I do it?
- Will both accounts become only one?
- Will the views and the subscribers be merged, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unfortunately, you can’t merge or link separate YouTube channels.](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2404846)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the channel owners to Google Plus pages, then the owner of the pages as your account.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKRrBByNuKM

Answer (score -1):

You can't merge YouTube channels. What you can do is bring different YouTube channels under one G+ account.